# How to transform elements of a Flowable using information from a Single

Tags: rx-java2

I have a `Flowable<Entity> entities`and a `Single<Set<Long>> attributeTypesToInclude`. I would like to modify each `entity` - remove the attributes not present in `attributeTypesToInclude` and return the transformed `Flowable<Entity>`. If it weren't a single I could've just used a `map` over `entities`. I'm not sure how to achieve this with a `Single` involved.

Sample definitions of `Entity` and `Attribute`:

```
class Entity {
  List<Attribute> attributes;
}

class Attribute {
  long type;
  String value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `flatMapSingle` is what I was looking for. This could work:

```
entities
  .flatMapSingle(entity -> transformEntitySingle(entity, attributesToInclude));

Single<Entity> transformEntitySingle(Entity entity, Single<List<Long>> attributesToInclude) {
  return attributesToInclude
    .map(attrs -> transformEntity(entity, attrs))
}

Entity transformEntity(Entity entity, List<Long> attributes) {
  // Fairly trivial
}
```